# Write vector tiles in QGIS 3.16 (writevectortiles_xyz)

Tags: qgis, vector-tiles

QGIS 3.16 offers a processing-tool `writevectortiles_xyz`

(My project contains a simple test-polygon-layer with just one feature, with default-style.)

I used following settings (extend from layer):

[image: settings]

After running this tool, the directory was created as expected with xyz-subdirectories containing pbf-files. Exploring them by text-editor show, that they are not empty.

I established a new vector-tiles connection to the local directory "file://C:\DATEN\Temp\kacheln\test{z}{x}{y}.pbf" and used following settings:

[image]

and added the new vector-tile-layer.

Layer was added to layer-tree without problems. Marked it as "visible"

But no result is rendered in QGIS, the screen stays empty.

Tried several CRS (ESPG:28532 and ESPG:3857).
Zoomed to several zoom-levels/zoom to layer.
Used-default style-settings.

Sample-data/project from https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2020/06/10/vectortiles-part1/ worked without problems.

How can I create vector tiles from a QGIS-project and use the tiles in QGIS (or other apps).